# Moose: Loading object from file in the BUILD method

Tags: perl, build, moose

I have to read a file in the BUILD method and I want to use the load method of the MooseX::Storage package.
But this load method create a new object and so when I instatiate the object this isn’t the object read from file.  In the code below I create an object $m1 with state 2 to write the file, I create $m2 with no parameter to read the file but $m2 doesn’t contain the right value.
The package:

```
package mia;
use Moose;
use MooseX::Storage;

with Storage(format => 'JSON', io => 'File');

has 'nome'  => ( is     => 'rw', isa    => 'Str', default =>'',);
has 'stato' => ( is     => 'rw', isa    => 'Int', default =>1,);

sub BUILD { 
    my $self=shift;
    if ($self->stato==1){
        $self=mia->load("mia.dat");
    }
    if ($self->stato==2){
        $self->stato(0);
        $self->nome("prova");
        $self->store("mia.dat");    
    }
}

sub stampa(){
    my $self=shift;
    print $self->nome." ".$self->stato;
}
```

the main program

```
use mia;
my $m;

$m1=mia->new(stato=>2); 
$m2=mia->new();
print "\nm1 \n";
$m1->stampa();
print "\nm2 \n";
$m2->stampa();
```

Comment: You might want to reconsider your package/class name.  In Perl, the convention is that only pragmas should have all lower case names.  See perlstyle-- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code seems to be acting as if BUILD is a constructor, which it isn't -- it's more like a post-construction hook where you can perform other things like read values from a DB. You should instead either:

- store the result of `mia->load` in an attribute, and optionally use delegated methods to access it, or
- use the result of `mia->load` *as* the object, rather than constructing a separate one.

Here is an example of the first case, separating the MooseX::Storage object from the object that controls it:

```
package miaController;
use Moose;
use mia;

has 'nome'  => ( is     => 'rw', isa    => 'Str', default =>'',);
has 'stato' => ( is     => 'rw', isa    => 'Int', default =>1,);
has 'mia'   => ( is     => 'rw', isa    => 'mia', lazy => 1);

sub BUILD
{
    my $self = shift;
    if ($self->stato == 1)
    {
        $self->mia(mia->load("mia.dat"));
    }
    elsif ($self->stato == 2)
    {
        $self->stato(0);
        $self->nome("prova");
        $self->mia->store("mia.dat");
    }
}
sub stampa
{
    my $self = shift;
    print $self->nome." ".$self->stato;
}

package mia;
use Moose;
use MooseX::Storage;
with Storage(format => 'JSON', io => 'File');

package main:
use miaController;

my $m1=miaController->new(stato=>2);
my $m2=miaController->new();
print "\nm1 \n";
$m1->stampa();
print "\nm2 \n";
$m2->stampa();
```

Comment: Thank you Ether, but how I can use the result of mia->load as the object? If I write $self->load it generate en error....

Comment: @Gabriella: you are attempting to combine state variables (which you pass into the constructor) with an object whose constructor is the load method -- I've split them into two.